# Docker install WeasyPrint on Google Cloud Run for Python gives "Unable to locate package python-lxml"

Tags: python, docker, weasyprint

I am trying to install WeasyPrint on Google Cloud Run using Dockerfile. This gives error `Unable to locate package python-lxml`. What can I do to install Weasyprint?

**Dockerfile**

```
# Specify Python
FROM python:latest

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Open port
EXPOSE 8080

# Add Python script
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Install Weasyprint
RUN apt-get install -y python-lxml libcairo2 libpango1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
RUN pip install WeasyPrint

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set Pythons path
ENV PYTHONPATH /app

# Run script
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

**Build output**

```
starting build "e52c6efd-6ef4-47dd-b545-60bd7b90c529"

FETCHSOURCE
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://github.com/a/pdfs
 * branch            afbc93509425d5b21407cae07c1400bdbfae2cdb -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at afbc935 Autogenerate PDFs
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "Build"
Step #0 - "Build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0 - "Build": Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.132MB

Step #0 - "Build": Step 1/12 : FROM python:latest
Step #0 - "Build": latest: Pulling from library/python
Step #0 - "Build": Digest: sha256:30f9c5b85d6a9866dd6307d24f4688174f7237bc3293b9293d590b1e59c68fc7
Step #0 - "Build": Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 815c8c75dfc0
Step #0 - "Build": Step 2/12 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 9996805d690a
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container 9996805d690a
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 4234084722a2
Step #0 - "Build": Step 3/12 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 102f817b7e22
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container 102f817b7e22
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 7399700a9710
Step #0 - "Build": Step 4/12 : EXPOSE 8080
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 2cc1758ba13e
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container 2cc1758ba13e
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> b0f8f7fb316e
Step #0 - "Build": Step 5/12 : RUN mkdir /app
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 22f75153299b
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container 22f75153299b
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 4bfd53553c9c
Step #0 - "Build": Step 6/12 : WORKDIR /app
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 721718a67160
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container 721718a67160
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> e4fa70d738e0
Step #0 - "Build": Step 7/12 : COPY . .
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> dfa52ca88166
Step #0 - "Build": Step 8/12 : RUN apt-get install -y python-lxml libcairo2 libpango1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 2ef5ddbba608
Step #0 - "Build": Reading package lists...
Step #0 - "Build": Building dependency tree...
Step #0 - "Build": Reading state information...
Step #0 - "Build": Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
Step #0 - "Build": This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
Step #0 - "Build": is only available from another source
Step #0 - "Build": However the following packages replace it:
Step #0 - "Build":   libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0
Step #0 - "Build": 
Step #0 - "Build": [91mE: Unable to locate package python-lxml
Step #0 - "Build": E: Unable to locate package libpango1.0-0
Step #0 - "Build": E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libpango1.0-0'
Step #0 - "Build": E[0m[91m: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpango1.0-0'
Step #0 - "Build": E: Package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0' has no installation candidate
Step #0 - "Build": The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python-lxml libcairo2 libpango1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info' returned a non-zero code: 100
Finished Step #0 - "Build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 100
Step #0 - "Build": [0m
```

Comment: You probably need `python3-lxml`

Comment: That did not work.